# Create a Button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hey i want to create a button like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="click-me" id="myButton" onclick="myFunction()">
</body>
</html>
```

but i want to create from javascript, and i'm doing something really wrong cause my button does not seem

```js
var MyButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
MyButton.id = "Mybuttonid";
MyButton.className = "MyButtonclass";
MyButton.onclick("myFunction()");
Div.appendChild(MyButton); //i have others things working in this "Div" only this button doesn't appear
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a misuse of `onclick` in the posted code, if you check the console you could notice the following message :

> "Uncaught TypeError: MyButton.onclick is not a function"

To attach the click event using the `onclick` it should be :

```
MyButton.onclick = myFunction;
```

Else it will be better to attach the event using `addEventListener()` instead like :

```
MyButton.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var Div = document.getElementById("my_div");


var MyButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
MyButton.id = "Mybuttonid";
MyButton.className = "MyButtonclass";
MyButton.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
Div.appendChild(MyButton);

function myFunction(){
  alert('test');
}
```

```html
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

Comment: This was a mistake when I was writing this post, all the names are right, I've already edited.

Comment: Ooh i see, Updated my post.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki `MyButton.onclick = myFunction();` doesn't work, or at least not in jsfiddle. It got to be `MyButton.onclick = function(){ myFunction() };`, as i have done in my answer.

Comment: It should be `MyButton.onclick = myFunction;` note the extra `()` you've in your example.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I copied the extra `()` from your example.

Comment: You should'nt :D , fixed

Comment: That was what i was trying to tell you :P

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong because Button does not exists(but MyButton exists).
Instead of :

```
var MyButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
MyButton.id = "Mybuttonid";
MyButton.className = "MyButtonclass";
MyButton.onclick("myFunction()");
Div.appendChild(MyButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use   `addEventListener`  to add click event to the button; And change  `Div.appendChild(button);` to `Div.appendChild(MyButton);`

```js
function myFunction(){
  alert("here");
}

var Div = document.getElementById('div');

var MyButton = document.createElement("button");
MyButton.id = "Mybuttonid";
MyButton.innerHTML ="CLICK ME"
MyButton.className = "MyButtonclass";
MyButton.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
 
Div.appendChild(MyButton); //i have others think working in this "Div" only this button doesn't appear
```

```html
<div id="div">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In both HTML and Javascript, you are declaring your onclick function the wrong way. Instead of

```
<input type="button" value="click-me" id="myButton" onclick"myFunction()">
```

it should be

```
<input type="button" value="click-me" id="myButton" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Which means that this piece of code in Javascript here:

```
MyButton.onclick("myFunction()");
```

Should be

```
   MyButton.onclick = function(){ myFunction() };
```

By doing this and solving the typo that other users mentioned, it should work just fine.